# Blacklist the Joke tag

Tags: support, tag-block-request

I was quite surprised to discover that the [joke](/questions/tagged/joke) on SO [is still allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11952148/how-can-i-implement-a-come-from-feature-in-c). We should probably stop this.

Comment: That tag is a joke

Answer (score -1):

If it is not used by a certain number of questions over a period of time, it will silently be removed from SO.

I wouldn't be too worried, just edit that question and remove the [joke](/questions/tagged/joke) tag.

Comment: The main problem is that it keeps coming back. The whole point of blacklisting a tag is to *prevent* it from coming back, so that we don't have to keep getting rid of tags that we clearly don't want.